# hyperledger fabric : discover network topology graphically

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have just started working with Hyperledger Fabric. I was looking for a tool that would demonstrate graphically the entire network and its operations.

Is there any existing project that does that?

If not, I intend to create one. Would anyone like to collaborate? 
As a starting point, I am looking at using http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html . I understand that it will be worth including the following:

1. Organizations
2. MSPs
3. CAs
4. Peers
5. Channels

(please add to this list)

Looking through the [APIs](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html), I am trying to figure out the starting point. I was hoping to find something like Client.getOrganisations() to get a list of all organisations on the network, but it doesnt seem to exist. Any ideas how to discover all Organisations using the Node SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Entities in Hyperledger Fabric usually executed with Docker,Docker Swarm or Kubernetes environments, hence I'd suggest to take a look on [Weave Scope](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope) project which could provide quite good visualization for your docker containers deployment.